# VSCode - Custom react snippets not working in javascriptreact.json file and also javascript.json file

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode Version:

```
Version: 1.41.1
Commit: 26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0
Date: 2019-12-18T15:04:31.999Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.2.11-050211-generic
```

- OS Version: **Ubuntu 18.04**

Steps to Reproduce:

1. I followed the official doc for creating a new custoim snippet - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets
2. Open pallette > Type ‘snippet’ > Select ‘Configure User Snippets’ >

Then from the doropdown list of options, choosing “JavaScript React” for my React files and ‘Babel JavaScript’ for regular JS files.

3> Now included the below for my "react-classnames" snippet in vscode file 
~/.config/Code/User/snippets/javascriptreact.json

```
  "react-classnames": {
    "prefix": "clmi",
    "body": [
      "className={classes.}"
    ],
    "description": "react-classname"
  },
```

**However this issue does NOT occur when all extensions are disabled. i.e. when I launch VS Code with **

```
code --disable-extensions
```

And below are my list of extension ( Got it by running `$ code --list-extensions` )

```
2gua.rainbow-brackets
aaron-bond.better-comments
akamud.vscode-javascript-snippet-pack
alefragnani.Bookmarks
alefragnani.numbered-bookmarks
alexeyvax.vscode-open-native-terminal
bierner.markdown-preview-github-styles
chrisdias.vscode-opennewinstance
christian-kohler.npm-intellisense
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer
Compulim.compulim-vscode-closetag
DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
DigitalBrainstem.javascript-ejs-support
dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring
ecmel.vscode-html-css
eg2.tslint
eg2.vscode-npm-script
emilast.LogFileHighlighter
emmanuelbeziat.vscode-great-icons
Equinusocio.vsc-community-material-theme
Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme
equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons
eriklynd.json-tools
esbenp.prettier-vscode
fabiospampinato.vscode-open-in-terminal
faceair.ayu-one-dark
fms-cat.theme-monokaisharp
formulahendry.auto-close-tag
formulahendry.auto-complete-tag
formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
formulahendry.code-runner
formulahendry.terminal
gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion
gerane.Theme-Sunburst
ghgofort.neon-vommit
HookyQR.beautify
httpsterio.henna
ivanzusko.theme-jo-light
jasonnutter.search-node-modules
jdinhlife.gruvbox
jolaleye.horizon-theme-vscode
josef.rouge-theme
kamikillerto.vscode-colorize
kube.theme-kay
leizongmin.node-module-intellisense
MaxfieldWalker.vscode-color-theme-spirited-away
mdickin.markdown-shortcuts
mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel
michelemelluso.code-beautifier
mikestead.dotenv
mohsen1.prettify-json
monokai.theme-monokai-pro-vscode
mrmlnc.vscode-scss
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
ms-python.python
ms-vscode.node-debug2
ms-vscode.Theme-MaterialKit
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
msjsdiag.vscode-react-native
naumovs.color-highlight
nickdemayo.vscode-json-editor
Nimda.deepdark-material
Nuuf.theme-hackershaze
P-de-Jong.vscode-html-scss
philsinatra.nested-comments
PKief.material-icon-theme
pucelle.vscode-css-navigation
rafamel.subtle-brackets
rsbondi.highlight-words
sburg.vscode-javascript-booster
Shan.code-settings-sync
shardulm94.trailing-spaces
shubham-saudolla.lilac
sibiraj-s.vscode-scss-formatter
sldobri.daily
sleistner.vscode-fileutils
SmukkeKim.theme-setimonokai
sourcegraph.sourcegraph
sourcegraph.vscode-sourcegraph-theme
spywhere.guides
steoates.autoimport
streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
teabyii.ayu
trybick.terminal-zoom
ueno.react-native-code-styles
vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag
voldemortensen.rainbow-tags
vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons
wmaurer.change-case
xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets
yzhang.markdown-all-in-one
ZainChen.json
```

**Further, while trying to isolate the source - I disabled ONLY the below four snippet related third party extensions (while keeping the rest of the extensions enabled )**

`1. ES7 React/Redux/React-Native/JS snippets
2. JavaScript (ES6) snippets
3. HTML Snippets
4. JavaScript Snippet Pack`

**But the issue still persists (i.e. with above 4 extensions disabled ).**

I also completely purged and did a fresh installation of VS Code in my machine and the issue continued as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question as finally reached to the solution from VS Codes very helpful and great team (**https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88936**)

And this is how got closer to the source of the problem - got this strange behaviour, in a React Component.js file when I type the snippet ('clmi' in this case) - before the React Component File's return() statement, I get the expected behaviour.
But if I type the snippet ('clmi') inside the return() statement, I dont get anything. i.e. the snippet does not give me the code completion option inside the return () statment.

The source was that VSCode was not recognizing this file to be a "javascriptreact" language type.

**Solution was as below**

In a React Component's .js file, try the tokens inspector via "F1 > Inspect TM Scopes" and position the cursor at those insert position. That will tell you the detected, embedded language. Depending on your grammar it might be a different language

And bleow is what I am getting.
[image]

So as you can see, this not **JavaScript** nor **JavaScript React** but the **jsx-attr** language. So now I had to target that type with vscode snippet

So now, I put the whole snippet in the jsx-attr type target file
 `~/.config/Code/User/snippets/jsx-attr.json`

And now the custom snippets worked as expected.

Comment: Did not know about the target specific nature of snippets. Thanks. Now i understand why my snippets aren't working as well!

Comment: I had this exact problem but a different solution. In my snippets I did not have ´javascriptreact´ as a scope property - only ´"Print to console": {
  "scope": "javascript,typescriptreact",´